# Using of functions and lists from other Mathematica files

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, files-and-directories

I have a code in which I have to use some functions and lists and use them in the body of the code. If I want to type all of them in a file in Mathematica, that file becomes very very long. For example, I have

```
Func1[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_]:=f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
Func2[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_]:=f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
Func3[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_]:=f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
Func4[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_]:=f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
Func5[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_]:=f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5); ...

List1={...};
List2={...};
List3={...};
List4={...};
List5={...}; ...


the body of my code...
```

I have to use them these functions and lists in the body of my code. Is it possible to type those functions and lists in a separate file and call them in the body of the code then use them?

Comment: lookup [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html),[`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html) and [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html).

Comment: If you have the expressions already in another notebook, then you can just evaluate that notebook using NotebookEvaluate.

Comment: Could you please give me a simple code as an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have a notebook called "stuff.nb". In my case, I made one that has a single line:

```
a=100;
```

Now in another notebook (located in the same directory as stuff.nb), evaluate:

```
NotebookEvaluate[NotebookDirectory[] <> "stuff.nb"]
```

Everything in stuff.nb is evaluated and so $a$ takes on the value $100$. If you are not in the same directory, then you would need to use the correct path to get to stuff.nb

Comment: Is there a way to hide this code in a notebook so it executes but are not shown at print out? I would like to have the PDF clean of "initiations" and only relevant computations for the reader to see.

Comment: Thanks dear @bill s

Comment: @mf67 -- Place it in an initialization cell and close the cell. Then it will be executed when you first run something in the new notebook.